# React Native function scope (Call parent function from child function)

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get my head around the scope of functions. `_internalFunction` works well, but how do I call `_externalFunction` instead?

I've tried `self=this` and then `this._externalFunction` inside _renderRow and also tried `() => {this._externalFunction}` but it didn't work.

```
class sandbox extends Component {
    //some code removed for clarity

    _renderRow(item) {
      const _internalFunction = () => {
        Alert.alert('Internal');
      };
      return (<Text onPress={_internalFunction}>{item}</Text>);
    }

    _externalFunction() {
      Alert.alert('External');
    };
}
```

Here's the code in React Native Playground to fiddle with: 
https://rnplay.org/apps/5CIGvA

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you need to manually bind `this` to the instance. Here is a quote from [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#autobinding):

> In React components declared as ES6 classes, methods follow the same
>   semantics as regular ES6 classes. This means that they don't
>   automatically bind `this` to the instance. You'll have to explicitly
>   use `.bind(this)` in the constructor:

Therefore you need to bind your function in constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this._externalFunction = this._externalFunction.bind(this);
}
```

And then you can use `this._externalFunction` in your component:

```
_renderRow(item) {
    return (<Text onPress={this._externalFunction}>{item}</Text>);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that another way you could do this is by using arrow functions, so
`_renderRow = (item) => { return () }`

This works because of lexical binding. I find this a bit cleaner than binding everything manually in my constructor.

Comment: Hmm.. When I did exactly what was proposed in the main reply it didn't work. Nothing happens when I click. However what was in the comment above worked perfectly with `return (<Text onPress={this._externalFunction}>{item}</Text>);}` Not sure how I should accept this answer, since the main one seems correct, but didn't work for me. I'm pretty sure I did it like you wrote.

Comment: can you try doing the binding on the prop instead? <Text onPress={_externalFunction.bind(this)}>{item}</Text>

Comment: I might have misunderstood you, but this actually works: `renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}`. In that case, I don't have to use the arrow function nor binding in the constructor. Is there any downside to this? I'm just happy it works :)